# How to design a form with many options?

Tags: website-design, forms

So here is the stuff that is needed on the form:

1. Name (short text)
2. Description (longer text)
3. Choose an option (basically a radio button, might be 10-100 options. The. options are presented on a small card)
4. Start date (date)
5. End date (date)
6. Submit button

The issue I am having is presenting the "Choose an option" in an optimal way. I have two ideas for solving this. The first idea is to have a simple linear form, present the first 3 options and have a "more" button. Here is a quick illustration:

[image: Illustration]

The second option would be a two-step wizard, but as we all know

> It’s silly to have a 2-step wizard...

I still think the wizard is the way to go, but I am very unsure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things that you should consider (wrt your context):

1. Form alignment approach: Go for the "top to bottom approach"(which you have done currently)i.e one-column approach.
2. Do not hide labels once the user taps into the field. Keep labels visible always.
3. Radio buttons are preferred when your options are limited to 3 or 4. If you have more than 4 options, use the "dropdown" multi-select element along with a search inside
4. Avoid using "more". This is not intuitive here.
5. The start and end date can be placed in one line.